# Rule based select with source tracking

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is an example of the sample dataset that I am having trouble writing an efficient SQL:

[image]

1. There is a target table `T1` with 5 columns ID (primary key), NAME, CATEGORY, HEIGHT, LINEAGE
2. `T1` gets data from 3 sources - `source1, source2, source3`
3. A map table defines the rule as to which column has to be picked in what order from which source
4. If a source has NULL value for a column, then check the next source to get the value - that's the rule
5. So the values for target table columns based on the rules are as below for ID = 1:

   ```
    Name: A12, CATEGORY: T1, HEIGHT: 4, Lineage: S3-S1-S1
   ```

   The values for target table columns based on the rules are as below for ID = 2:

   ```
    NAME: B, CATEGORY: T22, HEIGHT: 5, Lineage: S3-S2-S1
   ```
6. The logic to merge into target should look like this:

   ```
    Merge into Target T
    using (select statement with rank based rules from 3 source tables) on 

    when matched then

    when not matched then
   ```

**Question**: any suggestions on writing this `Merge` in an efficient way which also should update the Lineage in the merge?

Comment: Can you explain how the map works? Are there any indications for the ID? Is the sample Lineage you described correct?

Comment: ID is the Primary key in the target, that's a given. The logic is to build the best record for ID using the priority from MAP table and push that one best record into the target. Lineage tells which column value came from which source for ID after apply the priority Rule.

Comment: Assume that s1, s2, s3 are short names for SOURCE1, SOURCE2, SOURCE 3 in another metadata Table.

Comment: But on what basis did you choose S3-S1-S1 for the first example and S3-S2-S1 for the second? What is the mapping key?

Comment: The MAP table says, the best provider of NAME is SOURCE3, if NULL then SOURCE1 else SOURCE2. So for ID 1, SOURCE3 has 'A12' and hence lineage for NAME for ID 1 is S3. Actually its S3-S2-S1 for both. it's a typo above, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, the MAP table must have a column that will give **priority** to the mapping.
- Then you should PIVOT this table.
- The next step is to combine UNION ALL of all source tables.
- And finally, we can join all and select our values with the FIRST_VALUE function.
- Having such a result, you can substitute it in MERGE.

Structure and sample data for testing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE SOURCE1 (
    ID int,
    NAME string,
    CATEGORY string,
    HEIGHT numeric);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE SOURCE2 (
    ID int,
    NAME string,
    CATEGORY string,
    HEIGHT numeric);
    
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE SOURCE3 (
    ID int,
    NAME string,
    CATEGORY string,
    HEIGHT numeric);    
    
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MAP (
    PRIORITY int,
    SOURCE_COLUMN string,
    SOURCE_TABLE string);
    
INSERT INTO SOURCE1 (ID, NAME, CATEGORY, HEIGHT)
VALUES (1, 'A', 'T1', 4), 
       (2, 'B', 'T2', 5),
       (3, 'C', 'T3', 6);    
       
INSERT INTO SOURCE2 (ID, NAME, CATEGORY, HEIGHT)
VALUES (1, 'A1',  'T1',  4.4), 
       (2, 'B1',  'T22', 6),
       (3,  NULL, 'T3',  7.2);     
       
INSERT INTO SOURCE3 (ID, NAME, CATEGORY, HEIGHT)
VALUES (1, 'A12', 'T21', NULL), 
       (2, 'B',    NULL, 6),
       (3, 'C3', 'T3',   NULL);     
       
INSERT INTO MAP (PRIORITY, SOURCE_COLUMN, SOURCE_TABLE)
VALUES (1, 'NAME',     'SOURCE3'), 
       (2, 'NAME',     'SOURCE1'),
       (3, 'NAME',     'SOURCE2'), 
       (1, 'CATEGORY', 'SOURCE2'),
       (2, 'CATEGORY', 'SOURCE3'), 
       (3, 'CATEGORY', 'SOURCE1'),
       (1, 'HEIGHT',   'SOURCE1'), 
       (2, 'HEIGHT',   'SOURCE2'),
       (3, 'HEIGHT',   'SOURCE3');
```

And my suggestion for a solution:

```
WITH _MAP AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM MAP
  PIVOT (MAX(SOURCE_TABLE) FOR SOURCE_COLUMN IN ('NAME', 'CATEGORY', 'HEIGHT')) AS p(PRIORITY, NAME, CATEGORY, HEIGHT)
), _SRC AS (       
  SELECT 'SOURCE1' AS SOURCE_TABLE, ID, NAME, CATEGORY, HEIGHT FROM SOURCE1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SOURCE2' AS SOURCE_TABLE, ID, NAME, CATEGORY, HEIGHT FROM SOURCE2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SOURCE3' AS SOURCE_TABLE, ID, NAME, CATEGORY, HEIGHT FROM SOURCE3
)
SELECT DISTINCT _SRC.ID, 
       FIRST_VALUE(_SRC.NAME) OVER(PARTITION BY _SRC.ID ORDER BY MN.PRIORITY) AS NAME,
       FIRST_VALUE(_SRC.CATEGORY) OVER(PARTITION BY _SRC.ID ORDER BY MC.PRIORITY) AS CATEGORY,
       FIRST_VALUE(_SRC.HEIGHT) OVER(PARTITION BY _SRC.ID ORDER BY MH.PRIORITY) AS HEIGHT, 
       REPLACE(FIRST_VALUE(_SRC.SOURCE_TABLE) OVER(PARTITION BY _SRC.ID ORDER BY MN.PRIORITY) || '-' ||
               FIRST_VALUE(_SRC.SOURCE_TABLE) OVER(PARTITION BY _SRC.ID ORDER BY MC.PRIORITY) || '-' ||
               FIRST_VALUE(_SRC.SOURCE_TABLE) OVER(PARTITION BY _SRC.ID ORDER BY MH.PRIORITY), 'SOURCE', 'S') AS LINEAGE
  FROM _SRC
  LEFT JOIN _MAP AS MN ON _SRC.SOURCE_TABLE = MN.NAME AND _SRC.NAME IS NOT NULL
  LEFT JOIN _MAP AS MC ON _SRC.SOURCE_TABLE = MC.CATEGORY AND _SRC.CATEGORY IS NOT NULL
  LEFT JOIN _MAP AS MH ON _SRC.SOURCE_TABLE = MH.HEIGHT AND _SRC.HEIGHT IS NOT NULL;
```

Result:

```
+----+------+----------+--------+----------+
| ID | NAME | CATEGORY | HEIGHT | LINEAGE  |
+----+------+----------+--------+----------+
|  1 | A12  | T1       |      4 | S3-S2-S1 |
|  2 | B    | T22      |      5 | S3-S2-S1 |
|  3 | C3   | T3       |      6 | S3-S2-S1 |
+----+------+----------+--------+----------+
```